# extract value of id from website to excel

Tags: excel, vba

Good Nigth.

I tried the next code as Excel´s function, to extract the value of the **id=LblNombre**, but i get an error in excel

```
Function Registro(RTN As String)
   Dim IE As Object
   Dim Respuesta As String

   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "http://enlacertn.sar.gob.hn"
    IE.Visible = True
   While IE.busy
    DoEvents
   Wend
   IE.document.All.Item("txtCriterio").Value = RTN
   IE.document.All("btnBuscar").Click
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

   Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
   Loop
   Respuesta = IE.document.getElementById("LblNombre").innertext
   Registro = Respuesta
  IE.Quit
End Function
```

these are the screenshots

[Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYpm2.jpg)

[Before Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmwDa.jpg)

[After Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqOjD.jpg)

[Web code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfoyD.jpg)

I need help because this function help me to improve my job

Thanks,

Comment: please post the error logs/trace also.

Comment: these are the screenshots

[Excel Error][1]


[Before Query][2]


[After Query][3]

[Web code][4]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYpm2.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmwDa.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqOjD.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfoyD.jpg

Comment: Help me please!